# Embedded MATLAB function- Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to use Embedded MATLAB function but everytime it is making the same error. Can anybody explain what does it mean and how to resolve it. I have done work on MATLAB but this is the first time i am working on Simulink.
error is:

```
Message : Model error
source : unknown
reported by :simulink
summary : 

Error using ==> stateflow\private\slsf

Error using ==> stateflow\private\autobuild_kernel

Error using ==> stateflow\private\targetman

Error using ==> cd

Cannot CD to C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB71\work\sfprj\ (Name is nonexistent or not a directory).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which directory is your Simulink model located? It looks like it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB71\work`. Try saving it in a different directory where you have write access, such as `My Documents\MATLAB` and try again.

Also have you set up a C compiler? Embedded MATLAB Functions use C code generation so need a C compiler to compile the generated C code. Use `mex -setup` to to setup the C compiler.

Comment: hey thanks..it is working now. i have just changed the file location.  :)